# twitter authentication using signpost android

Tags: android, api, twitter

```
httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, CALLBACKURL);            
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

Used this code for authenticating app with twitter.

I successfully got authenticated with twitter from my application. But, my doubt is once I uninstall the application and install again its forwarding to the auth url. Once Authorize app is clicked its forwarding back to my application. I was able to enter username, password only the first time. From next time onwards the twitter's webpage for entering username, password itself is not coming.

Why is that so ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: because of in cookies or in cache there is stored username and password...so, clear that..so, you can get twitter login page again..

Comment: @MehulRanpara u mean i need to clear the cache within the browser ? Actually, I am not saving that in the shared preferences.

Comment: just use below link and integrate your app with twitter...

Comment: Ok. I got it now. If credentials are saved then only Authorize app button will come. Even there is a sign out button on the top. If signed out we can re login again. So is it better to use AndroidTwitter or twitter4j api for twitter integration ?

Comment: the best way is AndoridTwitter..because this not take you out of the application..

Comment: The other thing is like AndroidTwitter in turn makes use of twitter4J. I was thinking like AndroidTwitter is like twitter4J. Just a note. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22047/discussion-between-chaitanya-and-mehul-ranpara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just logout from Twitter to show login page.

```
private Boolean clearCredentials() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
        edit.remove(Constants.TWITTER_FLAG);
        edit.commit();

        return true;
    }
```